# Как правильно выполнить цикл и заполнить массив C#

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток, помогите разобраться как выполнить цикл при заполнении массива. 
Вот есть класс с переменными:

```
 internal class Transhipment
 { 
  public float Weight { get; set; }

  public float WeightThin { get; set; }

  public float WeightThick { get; set; }

  public float KalN { get; set; }

  public float KalV { get; set; }

  public float ResourceShaft { get; set; }

  public float[] FloatReserv { get; set; }

  public int[] IntReserv { get; set; }
 }
```

Далее я заполняю данными из файла и помещаю все в List:

```
 var transhipment = new Transhipment()
 {
  Weight = read.ReadSingle(),

  WeightThin = read.ReadSingle(),

  WeightThick = read.ReadSingle(),

  KalN = read.ReadSingle(),

  KalV = read.ReadSingle(),

  ResourceShaft = read.ReadSingle(),

  FloatReserv = new[] {read.ReadSingle()},

  IntReserv = new[] {read.ReadInt32()}
 };

  result.Add(transhipment);
```

Но FloatReserv и IntReserv мне нужно выполнить в цикле, если написать внутри for я получаю ошибку, если вынести за скобки и написать:

```
transhipment.FloatReserv[1] = read.ReadSingle();
```

Получаю исключение Null. Помогите разобраться пожалуйста. Спасибо

Comment: Можете привести содержимое файла?  Желательно,  с комментариями,  что есть что?

Comment: Используйте вместо массивов `List<int>` и `List<float>`. А вот такая запись `IntReserv = new[] {read.ReadInt32()}` создает массив размером в один элемент, и потому возникает ошибка при попытке сделать это: `transhipment.FloatReserv[1] = read.ReadSingle();`. И в дополнение: всякий раз когда вы будете начинать создавать новый массив, тут же вспоминайте, что вы пишите на C#, а у него есть типизированные коллекции, например List<T>.

Comment: @Bulson Хорошо но мне нужно за 1 проход заполнить 4 раза данными, не совсем понимаю как это сделать ?

Comment: Вариантов много, вот один из них: создайте в классе методы `SetFloatReserv(IEnumerable<float> data)` , ну и для второго свойства подобный для заполнения данными

Comment: А откуда вы знаете, сколько элементов будет в `FloatReserv`?

Comment: @VladD У меня есть исходник в котором я знаю сколько фиксированных значений в данном классе должно быть.

Comment: @Ethernets: Тогда `FloatReserv = new[] {read.ReadSingle(), read.ReadSingle(), read.ReadSingle() }`?

Comment: @VladD Ох.... забыл что так тоже можно. Вы простите за наглость, если есть у вас время, не могли бы вы показать более красивый и правильный вариант ? Хочется учиться правильным подходам и чистому коду. Спасибо. Оформите как ответ.

Comment: @Ethernets: Написал ответ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Простой способ — если количество чисел известное и небольшое, можно написать так:

```
FloatReserv = new[] { read.ReadSingle(), read.ReadSingle(), read.ReadSingle() },
```

(для трёх).

Если количество элементов станет известно лишь во время выполнения, то проще всего написать вспомогательный метод:

```
static float[] ReadMany(int howMuch, BinaryReader read)
{
    var result = new float[howMuch];
    for (int i = 0; i < howMuch; i++)
        result[i] = read.ReadSingle();
    return result;
}
```

и соответственно

```
FloatReserv = ReadMany(3, read),
```

---

Можно ещё, конечно, использовать LINQ-выражение

```
FloatReserv = Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(n => read.ReadSingle()).ToArray(),
```

но оно на мой вкус не очень читабельно.

Comment: Большое вам спасибо.

Comment: @Ethernets: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

Здесь нужно передавать ссылку на read в конструктор класса Transhipment.  Внутри конструктора можно будет объявить цикл for.
PS: если покажете формат файла,  опишу более детально.